# How do I convert to DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, dictionary, arraylist

How do I convert `DataFrame` from this code?

```py
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
# model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
results = cross_validate(pipe_countvect, X_train,y_train, cv=kfold, return_train_score=True, scoring=list(scoring.values()))
    
print('K-fold cross-validation results:', results)

for sc in range(len(scoring)):
  print(pipe_countvect.__class__.__name__+" average %s: %.3f (+/-%.3f)" % 
              (list(scoring.keys())[sc], results['test_%s' % list(scoring.values())[sc]].mean(), 
                               results['test_%s' % list(scoring.values())[sc]].std()))
```

The output of the code is the following.

> K-fold cross-validation results: {'fit_time': array([0.30717778, 0.29981613, 0.27626038, 0.27626109, 0.28423905]), 'score_time': array([0.0718081 , 0.06582379, 0.06582284, 0.06682134, 0.06582308]), 'test_accuracy': array([0.76775707, 0.78052913, 0.76945132, 0.78222338, 0.77479473]), 'train_accuracy': array([0.79682002, 0.79264955, 0.78929363, 0.79499544, 0.79369217]), 'test_precision': array([0.25067144, 0.25070822, 0.25201432, 0.26953673, 0.25011328]), 'train_precision': array([0.28875203, 0.28787879, 0.28236355, 0.28549954, 0.28791537]), 'test_recall': array([0.83832335, 0.8455414 , 0.85173979, 0.83965015, 0.8832    ]), 'train_recall': array([0.95576923, 0.95719697, 0.96049099, 0.95623548, 0.94740825]), 'test_roc_auc': array([0.89926785, 0.90735343, 0.90181992, 0.89995133, 0.91307957]), 'train_roc_auc': array([0.94469257, 0.94378419, 0.94269082, 0.94410081, 0.94276353]), 'test_f1': array([0.38594073, 0.38674436, 0.38894646, 0.40807651, 0.38983051]), 'train_f1': array([0.4435124 , 0.44263444, 0.43642702, 0.43971505, 0.44162257])

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you have a simple dictionary there, so I don't see any problem, you can convert it directly to a pandas dataframe. Assuming that your `array` object is a numpy array, here is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import array

results = {
    'fit_time': array([0.30717778, 0.29981613, 0.27626038, 0.27626109, 0.28423905]),
    'score_time': array([0.0718081 , 0.06582379, 0.06582284, 0.06682134, 0.06582308]),
    'test_accuracy': array([0.76775707, 0.78052913, 0.76945132, 0.78222338, 0.77479473]),
    'train_accuracy': array([0.79682002, 0.79264955, 0.78929363, 0.79499544, 0.79369217]),
    'test_precision': array([0.25067144, 0.25070822, 0.25201432, 0.26953673, 0.25011328]),
    'train_precision': array([0.28875203, 0.28787879, 0.28236355, 0.28549954, 0.28791537]),
    'test_recall': array([0.83832335, 0.8455414 , 0.85173979, 0.83965015, 0.8832 ]),
    'train_recall': array([0.95576923, 0.95719697, 0.96049099, 0.95623548, 0.94740825]),
    'test_roc_auc': array([0.89926785, 0.90735343, 0.90181992, 0.89995133, 0.91307957]),
    'train_roc_auc': array([0.94469257, 0.94378419, 0.94269082, 0.94410081, 0.94276353]),
    'test_f1': array([0.38594073, 0.38674436, 0.38894646, 0.40807651, 0.38983051]),
    'train_f1': array([0.4435124 , 0.44263444, 0.43642702, 0.43971505, 0.44162257])
}
    

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```